# can jax-ws client work with jax-rpc services?

Tags: web-services

I am just curious on this: Can a JAX-WS client work with JAX-RPC service?

Even if the service is using the document/literal(wrapped), and how do I know the service is JAX-RPC or JAX-WS?

Comment: I have excactly the same issue: we have to consume an old JAX-RPC WS and we are trying to generate the client Java classes with the jaxws-maven-plugin, but it is only generate @SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC). It looks we have to manually construct the Request as a string. I would be interested to see if there is any wrapper or (plugin) options to better integrate them.